# How to convert a number into a NaN value in python?

Tags: python, numbers, google-colaboratory, nan

I have a negative value that affects my graph. I need to know how to convert for example, -66.23 into a NaN value. Thank you!

Comment: What is your data structure? numpy array? pandas dataframe? python list? What is your graph? matplotlib? plotly?

Comment: Hello, for example I imported a table with data on it. One data specifically is like an uncertainty number (if that makes sense). I need to convert that into a NaN value in order for my graph to plot correctly. It's a data frame from pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace all negative values use the pandas built-in `Fancy indexing`:

```
df[df < 0] = float('NaN')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace a value by another:

```
>>> df.replace(-66.23, float('NaN'))
```